# Proper Syntax for Declaring a Draw in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a tic tac toe game. Someone already taught me how to get the winner declared and stop further play.

There are two persistent problems. The first is that when the wins are straight across, the counters add 1 to the x wins and 2 to the o wins. The second issue is that I can't get the game to call a draw. I have tried else if without results.

Here is the whole js and the game can be seen at: http://jvonhausen.com/final/p19/

```
jQuery(function() {

    $('#start').click(clear_squares);

    $('.square').click(function () {    
        square_stuff(this);
    });

});

var player_x = true; 
var complete = false; 
var winner = '';
var x_wins = 0;
var o_wins = 0;
var draw = 0;

function clear_squares () {
    localStorage.setItem('x_count', x_wins); 
    localStorage.setItem('o_count', o_wins); 
    localStorage.setItem('draw_count', draw); 

    $('.square').html(''); 

    player_x = true;
    $('#output').html('turn: x');

    complete = false; //allows for new game
}


function square_stuff (square) {
    if (!complete) {
        if ($(square).html() == '') {       
            if (player_x == true) {
                $(square).html('x');
                player_x = false;               
            } else {            
                $(square).html('o');
                player_x = true;                
            }
        }
    }   
    check_squares();
}

function check_squares () {
    complete = true;
    var values = new Array(); 
    var winner = '';

    $('.square').each(function () {     
        values.push( $(this).html());
        if ($(this).html() == '') complete = false;
        if ( !winner && values[0] == values[1] && values[1] == values[2] ) winner = values[0];
        if ( !winner && values[3] == values[4] && values[4] == values[5] ) winner = values[4];
        if ( !winner && values[6] == values[7] && values[7] == values[8] ) winner = values[7];
        if ( !winner && values[0] == values[3] && values[3] == values[6] ) winner = values[3];
        if ( !winner && values[1] == values[4] && values[4] == values[7] ) winner = values[1];
        if ( !winner && values[2] == values[5] && values[5] == values[8] ) winner = values[5];
        if ( !winner && values[0] == values[4] && values[4] == values[8] ) winner = values[8];
        if ( !winner && values[2] == values[4] && values[4] == values[6] ) winner = values[2];      
        if (winner) {           
            complete = true;
            $('#output').html('winner: ' + winner);
            if ($(this).html() == 'x') {
                localStorage.setItem('x_count', x_wins); 
                x_wins++;
                $('#wins_x').val(x_wins);
            } 
            if ($(this).html() == 'o') {
                localStorage.setItem('o_count', o_wins); 
                o_wins++;
                $('#wins_o').val(o_wins);
            }
            if (winner == '' && complete == true) { 
                $('#output').html('no winner');
                localStorage.setItem('draw_count', draw); 
                draw++;
                $('#draws').val(draw);
            }   
        }                   
        if (winner == '' && complete == false) {    
            if (player_x == true) {     
                $('#output').html('turn: x');
            } else {        
                $('#output').html('turn: o');
            }       
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you can reference my javascript version of tic-tac-toe at http://www.selbie.com/ttt  It might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not breaking out of you "each" loop once you detect a winner.  I think this will work:

```
$('.square').each(function () {  
    if (winner) {
       return;
    }   
    values.push( $(this).html());
    ....
```

Alternatively, this is just cleaner:

```
function check_squares () {
complete = true;
var values = []; // better way to declare an empty array
var winner = '';

// build the values array first
$('.square').each(function () {     
    values.push( $(this).html());
}

// then just check for a winner once... 
if ( !winner && values[0] == values[1] && values[1] == values[2] ) winner = values[0];
....
```

And the reason why your code isn't detecting a draw is because your check for draw is occuring inside the "if (winner)" block.

```
   if (winner) {           
        complete = true;
        ....

        // the clause will never get executed, because winner must have already been set to have made it this far
        // so winner == '' will aways be false
        if (winner == '') { 
            $('#output').html('no winner');
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for this. The winner returned works well for keeping the score correctly. And, while the draw error you described makes perfect sense, and thus I moved the condition to the same area as the continue play condition, still no draw results:

Comment: Okay, thanks for this. The winner returned works well for keeping the score correctly. And, while the draw error you described makes perfect sense, and thus I moved the condition to the same area as the continue play condition, still no draw results occur.

Comment: Do you know how to debug javascript?  On IE, just press F12.  On Firefox, just install the Firebug plugin.  Chrome has something similar. I'm certain if you started setting break points in your code, you'd discover the problem.

Comment: Also, it's meaningless to check the complete flag (for tree or false if "winner" is still ''.  So I adjusted my answer above as appropriate.